# Google adsense not display in angular 4 website

Tags: angular, adsense

I'm working on a new website and use angular 4. I created a very simple component to display the google adsense. Just a container div which inside I only copied-paste the standard script from my adsense. But, it's doesn't show

Is anybody encountered this issue?

I'm not paste a code because there isn't too much to show. the html template looks something like:

```
<div>
    script
</div>
```

and then I just use the component's tag. But, the banner will not display. Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't put a script tag in a template

Comment: use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-adsense